# scale subviews to fit inside uiview

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

What I'm trying to do is very simple...i think.  I want to make sure all the subviews within a view in my view controller are scaled to fit. Inside it.

My view controller has a menuview (subclass of uiview).  Within that there are uiimage views, labels, and a button.  The MenuView class I created has a nib file with a uiimage view that I want to scale to the size of the menuview depending on the device used.  I'm not sure if the menuview is not staying constrained to the screen or if the uiiimage isn't, but when i run my program the menu runs off the screen.

Question:
- Can I force this (uiview and/or uiimageview) to stay on the screen using storyboard (programmatically is ok, but would prefer to try with storyboard)?

If anyone can point me to a good introduction to auto layout view and understanding the mainstoryboard that'd also be appreciate because it's insanely frustrating.

Screenshot: in the image below you can see I have a letter image that I want within the limits of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you included some images showing what you want and what you've got now.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot on your Mac.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361)

Comment: By the way, you can take a Simulator screenshot by simply pressing CMD+S.

Comment: Any thoughts on what's happening.  Behind the menuview is an uibutton in the botton right corner. That could be part of the issue but I'm not sure.